# how to create 3d cylinder matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a filled 3d shape that will look similar to this: (long round object)

[image]

(no need for the round part at the top, one color for all the object is good)

I've tried to create many similar circles with different center point but it didn't work, and with cylinder all I got was weird shapes.

Comment: Can you give what you tried?

Comment: Maybe change the question title. That's not a cylinder.

Comment: how did you get weird shapes with `cylinder` ? Show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

To make a cylinder the exact name exists as a command:

```
figure;
cylinder(0.1,20);
axis equal;
```

[image]